# Conditional Branch with Assign in stage in OSB

Tags: branch, conditional-statements, transformation, osb

I hava a conditional branch in a proxy service, but I need to invoke one if the value is 'old', if not, the flow goes to the default.

the thing is that this value must be editable, it means this value is not sent in the request of the service, it can be changed in the OSB Console, I was trying to use a stage before the Conditional Branch and a variable, but this one can be accessed from the Cond. branch (Out of scope)

I don't know what is the best way for implementing this, that the value is editable from OSB and not sent in the request

Any ideas?

thank you

Comment: "This value must be editable" - please provide details of typical use cases. How many non default options will be there at any given time? How often are those changed and what's the trigger for change (time or ...)? Is set of all possible values constant (with some "disabled") or are new values added over time and old removed entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all of the details on what you're doing, but have you considered putting this in a database table?  You would then use some simple callout on your conditional to check the age of a row.

Is there a particular reason that you would need to edit this in OSB itself?  I would rather get it implemented, click the **Activate** button, and never touch it again.  Minimize exposure to accidental changes elsewhere, etc.